# In Azure ML timeseries forecasting, Model Explanations, how do I upload actual values?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Using Azure ML through the web UI. I'm doing a timeseries forecasting automl training job. In the explanations tab for a model, how can I upload the actual data for the forecast period to compare. See the red circled box in the image below.

[image: Example Explanation GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently developing test-set ingestion in the UI. However, currently there is no way to upload test data through the UI to populate these graphs. This experience can only be accessed by kicking off an explanation through the SDK with the test data. We refer to this as "Interpretability at inference time" and have some documentation on how to do this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-machine-learning-interpretability-aml#interpretability-at-inference-time

Test-set ingestion is scoped to land for private preview before end of June. Let's keep in touch to ensure you get early access here.

Thanks,
Sabina